# Static initialization block versus static initialization method in java

Tags: java, static-initialization

I was reading about the static initialization block in the Java documentation and I found this:

> The advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused
> later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.

This is basically talking about using *private static methods* as an alternative to static initialization block and the quoted sentence is the advantage. I don't seem to make sense out of this. Can someone break this down further for me?

```
static {
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

VS

```
class Whatever {
    public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();
        
    private static varType initializeClassVariable() {

        // initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one only runs a single time. The second one can be invoked many times whenever you need.

Comment: A little bit more context for the quote would be helpful. In general, static initializers and static methods are different concepts, so it is hard to guess what the author meant without having more context.

Comment: @Turing85: Using private static methods as an alternative to static initialization block. Not the ordinary/general usage of static methods we normally do.

Comment: Again, dfferent concepts. Static initializers have a very specific purpose: they are executed by the JVM when the class is loaded. We can - of course - move the code from a static initializer to a (private) static methods so we can call the code again later on, and call this method in the static initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinitialize if you need to, reusing the same code.  For example:

```
 public void doSomething() {
    ...
    if (theSkyHasFallen) {
        // Uh-oh, we need to completely reinitialize
        myVar = initializeClassVariable();
    }
    ...
 }
```

So, if you have to reinitialize, it makes sense to factor your initialization code into a static method so that you can reuse it.

Personally, I use static initialization methods when I feel the logic is better shown by so doing, on a case-by-case basis.  If, for example, the static variable needs a little computation to determine the right value, it seems clearer to write a method that specifically does the computation.

An example might be

```
private static Map<String, Thing> map = initMap();
 :
private static Map<String, Thing> initMap() {
   Map<String, Thing> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("X", new Thing(....);
   map.put("Y", new Thing(....);
     :
   return map;
 }
```

I find it to be better structure to put the map construction and initialization into a method that is specifically targeted at delivering a completely-initialized map.  For me, the structural aspect wins, regardless of whether I ever need to "reinitialize" later.

Comment: Please does reinitialization mean assigning a different value? I think that's what I don't understand.

Comment: Depends entirely on you. In my trivial first example, I imagined that the code could get itself into a state ('theSkyHasFallen') where the best thing to do is to reset the class variable to its initial value, for reasons known only to the programmer. But there might be circumstances where you'd want to set it to some different value (and maybe 'initializeClassVariable' needs some input arguments so it knows what to do), though I'd probably not use the word "reinitialize" for that case, since it's not resetting to the initial value.